# Samsung Galaxy s3 give null on getSupportActionBar()

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, samsung-mobile

I am using ActionBarSherlock in my android app. It works fine on every phone except Samsung Galaxy S3.

This particular line gives null pointer exception -

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(getString(R.color.headerBarColor))));
```

My Manifest looks like this -

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/adminlaunchericon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar" >
```

Here the getSupportActionBar() gives me null.

Now same piece of code works very well with other phone.

Any one has any such experience and if can tell me how to handle this.

Comment: What type of activity are you extending? Just a SherlockActivity?

Comment: I am extending SherlockActivity

Comment: Where are you calling `getSupportActionBar()`? After `setContentView()`?

Comment: Yes right after the setContentView()

Comment: For certain version of ABS I remember having to do this in onResume() and not onCreate(), maybe try that.

Comment: That didn't work either :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by removing the following line -

requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

I wonder why I put it in first place. But anyways, it might help someone else.